# Adding dynamic text to ArcGIS map documents

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, command-line

I've been making some map layouts and just noticed this command:

< dyn type="document" property="name"/>.mxd

It make possible to change automatically my current file name: http://prntscr.com/4sdzwl

I want to ask how does it works and how do I find some other commands that makes things like these quick and easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called '[dynamic text](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000013000000)' and is used with ArcMap Layouts:

> Dynamic text is text placed on a map layout that changes dynamically
>   based on the current properties of the map document, data frame, and
>   Data Driven Pages. Dynamic text works through the use of tags, like
>   HTML. Here is an example of a dynamic text tag for the title of a map
>   document:

```
 <dyn type="document" property="title"/>
```

Comment: I can't see the example. Only that, all your help was really useful. Going to do my research about this dynamyc text thing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: just one last question: This command= http://prntscr.com/4seuzh, is used to display labels in a different and more gentle way than the usual. It is part of dynamic code too? or is something else?

Comment: @EdixonGutierrez That is a label expression (from the ArcMap layer properties) that basically says: label this feature with values from 2 fields, the first line use [Vere_Nombr] then create a new line (VBNewLine) and display the value from [Vere_Nom_M]

Comment: thanks for the information, but do you know about a guide or something in order to know the expressions that are running for ArcGIS please

Comment: @EdixonGutierrez I think this is what you're after: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000027000000

Comment: It's part of what I'm looking for, but for example the expression I displayed first is not in there. But I think that I need basic concepts of scripting in order to know how does it works. @mapBaker

Comment: @EdixonGutierrez the link in the answer I submitted references the expression in your original question, relating to data driven pages and dynamic text. Your second question about label expressions is somewhat different, but that's what I linked to in my comment above...

Comment: The original question is alright is all I need. The next one I though there were a bit more info about it, but I'll look around with the reference you gave me. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment to the above answer, but didn't want to make a comment thread too long. Got scolded for that before.

Anyway, dynamic text is also available in map layouts; it's not limited to data driven pages. There are a variety of supported properties for dynamic text, and they can be combined with each other and static text. [ESRI help...](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Working_with_dynamic_text/00s900000013000000/)

Comment: updated my answer to reflect that notion...thank you!